# Binary search runs as slow as linear one, plus finding first value

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

I'm trying to implement a Density Map, this map is represented by 2D array of n x m dimensions, where each cell has a value between 0 and 1, representing the probability of randomly find this cell. For example :

```
0.04   0.06   0.10
0.50   0.01   0.05
0.09   0.10   0.05
```

We have a 50% chance to find the coordinates (1,0), 4% chance of finding the coordinates (0,0) and so on.

To find this cell, I use a cumulative sum. The above array would be then represented by :

```
0.04   0.69   0.90
0.54   0.70   0.95
0.63   0.80   1.00
```

Since I'm working in C++, I'm using a 1D array of size (n * m), the above is then represented by :

```
0.04   0.54   0.63   0.69   0.70   0.80   0.90   0.95   1.00
```

To find a random cell within this probability, I can use this linear method :

```
while (internal[i] < k) {
    if (internal[i] >= k) break;
    i++;
}
```

Where k is a random number between 0 and 1

This is, however, quite slow since my array is used to represent an image (so it can become quite large), and I have to call this function an unholy amount of times.

To speed up the program, I tried to implement a binary search in my array. This implementation is as follows :

```
int DensityMap::simple_binary_search(double value, int first, int last) {

int index = -1;
int mid_point;

while (first <= last) {
    mid_point = first + (last - first) / 2;

    if (value >= internal[mid_point] && value < internal[mid_point + 1]) {
        index = mid_point;
        break;
    } else if (value < internal[mid_point]) {
        last = mid_point - 1;
    } else {
        first = mid_point + 1;
    }

}

return index;
```

}

The returned index is correct (same as the linear search), but the speed gain is quite bad, and I can't understand why. For example, with a 10 000 x 10 000 randomly filled density map, the search takes 3.172s for the binary search, and 3.288s for the linear one.

Another problem I have with the binary search is that, sometimes, the results can differ a bit. Consider the following example :

```
Probability array -> 0.50   0.00   0.40   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.05   0.00   0.05
Cumulative sum    -> 0.50   0.50   0.90   0.90   0.90   0.90   0.95   0.95   1.00
```

In this case, if my random number is 0.90, the linear search will stop at the first occurence of this number (index 2), whereas the binary one will look at the mid index, where the value is also 0.90, so it will return (index 4) as its result, which is not what I want ..

Is there another way to speed up this search and keep the results as I want them ? (Meaning finding the first occurence of a value). I guess I could iterate in reverse once I find a result with the binary search, but I'm afraid it will slow down the program even more, which would be pretty horrendous

Thanks

Comment: your alghoritm looks ok. Did you check how many loops does the while make? Do you measure search time only, or the whole program run?

Comment: @erip std::binary_search only returns bool value, i.e. tests for existence.

Comment: @user2672165 Oops. :)

Comment: I only measured time for each method, but I didn't check the number of passage in while. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::lower_bound` which returns first element that is greater or equal than input (I.e exactly what you need) or check its implementation if you want to implement it yourself. Your problem that you stop when you have found element, you should treat equal elements as if they were bigger.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's exactly what I needed !

Comment: @B.Kovac Out of curiosity, how does it compare?

Comment: It's pretty comparable, which is odd since the complexity should be logarithmic according to the documentation, but it might be improved with random access iterator, I'm looking into it right now

Comment: if your iterator is not RandomAccessIterator, then it work in linear time (but in logarithmic number of comparisons)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using c++, you can use std::upper_bound method which will return exactly what you're willing to get (index of the *first occurence* of value greater than the given number)